# i am trying to fetch book data from amazon and show it with flutter but getting an error

Tags: python, flutter

this is the error that i get
python part works correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKCiz.png)

but flutter part is not working

A Dart VM Service on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:61813/7maaFtkUR3s=
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61813/7maaFtkUR3s=
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 942:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 575:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1581:7                                             
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37263:58

dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 321:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:amazonwebscraping/function.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String url = "";
  var data;
  String output = "Initial Output";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Amazon Web Scraping'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?input=' + value.toString();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  data = await fetchdata(url);
                  var decoded = jsonDecode(data);
                  setState(() {
                    output = decoded['Language'];
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Fetch ASCII Value',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                )),
            Text(output)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```